# R Shiny validate returning error when data is valid

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I have a shiny app that produces errors when there is no data, and I'm trying to use validate to produce a nicer error message. I've gotten it to work for the variables that don't have data, but then I get an error where there is data and a plot (or table) should appear.

Using the following code, I get the error below.

```
else if (input$geo=="Alaska, 2015") {
    data <- switch(
        validate(need(input$var != "Sexual Orientation", "Data Unavailable")),
        input$var, 
        "Housing Status" = hmlweightak,
        "Sex" = sexweightak,
        "Race/Ethnicity" = raceethweightak,
        "Sexual Orientation" = "",
        "Bullied at School in the last 12 Months" = bsweightak,
        "Missed School due to Safety Concerns" = usweightak,
        "Deliberately hurt by an intimate partner" = pvweightak,
        "Forced to Perform Sexual Acts by Intimate Partner in the last 12 Months" = saweightak,
        "Binge Drank in the last 30 days" = bdweightak,
        "First Tried Alcohol by Age 12" = faweightak,
        "First Tried Marijuana by Age 12" = fmweightak,
        "Suffered from Depression in the last 12 Months" = dweightak,
        "Had Suicidal Thoughts in the last 12 Months" = stweightak,
        "Attempted Suicide in the last 12 Months" = asweightak,
        "Required Medical Attention After Suicide Attempt in the last 12 Months" = smweightak,
        "Ever Used Illegal Drugs" = sdweightak,
        "Used Prescription Drugs Without a Prescription" = pdweightak,
        "Sexually Active by Age 13" = fiweightak,
        "Drank or Used Drugs Before Last Sexual Intercourse" = ddliweightak,
        "Breakfast in the Last 7 Days" = "",
        "Average Hours of Sleep per Night" = hsweightak,
        "Used a Condom During Last Sexual Intercourse" = clweightak,
        "Asthma" = aweightak
    )
}
```

[image]

I'm also getting this error when I include `get()` before `input$var`, and I was getting a different error at some point before, where it basically listed all of the variables but I can't seem to reproduce that now. This is just a tiny portion of code so please let me know if more code or screenshots would be helpful, but I'm hoping it's something simple since it seems to be half working. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your combination of the `switch` and `validate` statement.

Let's say based on your input$dropDownValue you want to return one or the other dataset. In case of `iris` `return datasets::iris`, you would need the following statement.

```
switch(input$dropDownValue,
       iris = datasets::iris,
       cars = datasets::cars)
```

`validate` just stops the execution of the function and adds the validation message if the first statement is evaluate to `FALSE`.

In your case it should be something like

```
validate(need(input$var != "Sexual Orientation", "Data Unavailable"))
data <- switch(input$var, 
               "Housing Status" = hmlweightak,
               "Sex" = sexweightak,
               [...]
               )
```

See the code below for an example of using `validate` and `switch`.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
   selectInput("dropDownValue", "Data", c("no data", "iris", "cars")),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    validate(
      need((input$dropDownValue == "iris" || input$dropDownValue == "cars"), "Please select a data set")
    )
    switch(input$dropDownValue,
           iris = datasets::iris,
           cars = datasets::cars)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(data()[, 1])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and is so simple! I can't believe I hadn't tried that, but thank you so much!